# Read Authorization header from response

Tags: http, request, authorization, fetch, superagent

I am working on a side project in which I want to reuse an existing API.
The API has an `/auth` endpoint which handles POST requests and expects the `email` and `password` in the request body. If the `email` and `password` are verified, then the server returns a response which contains an `Authorization` header which holds the value for the token which should be sent in all the subsequent requests.

I have a problem retrieving this header from the response. It is visible in both Postman and Chrome Dev Tools (Network section).
[image: Postman]
Chrome Dev tools:
[image: XMLHttpRequest]
`console.log` of the response headers
[image]

I have tried multiple libraries/implementations for sending requests (`superagent`, `request`, `fetch` implementation and even `XMLHttpRequest`), however, all of the responses I get have the `Authorization` header in the response headers when I look at them in the Chrome Dev Tools, but when I try to access the headers from javascript, I always end up getting the `Content-Type` header only.

I read in a couple of other answers that the server must specify the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` or `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` with the `Authorization` value in the headers, however, I do not have access to the server and there are no issues on the API related to this problem, so my guess is that I am missing something when sending the request.

Any ideas?

Here is the request using `fetch`

```
return fetch(endpoint, {
    method: 'post',
    body: data,
    headers: {
      [API_KEY_HEADER]: apiKey
    }
  }).then(r => {
    console.log(r);
    console.log(r.headers)
  });
```

Here is the request using `request`

```
r({
    url: endpoint,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      [API_KEY_HEADER]: apiKey
    }
  }).then(r => {
    console.log(r);
    console.log(r.headers);
  })
```

And here is plain old `XMLHttpRequest`

```
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('POST', endpoint);

  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.setRequestHeader(API_KEY_HEADER, apiKey);

  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log('Status:', this.status);
      console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
      console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    }
  };

  const body = {
    'email': 'dummy@test.com',
    'password': 'secret!'
  };

  request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

Comment: `Authorization` is a standard request header, not response header. Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields

Comment: BTW, can you post the code that send POST request?

Answer (score 10):

2 years too late but hope this helps someone with the same problem:

As @shaochuancs said, the Authorization header is not standard in the response, so the server has to explicitly inform to expose it. To do that the server must add the following header:

**Access-Control-Expose-Headers: authorization**

Source: https://www.yukei.net/2016/01/getting-response-headers-data-from-an-ajax-request-with-jquery/