# Response Header not accessible in JS

Tags: javascript, spring, authentication, redux, axios

I am using React + Redux on the front end and Spring for the backend. The reponse header contains Authorization header when viewed on browser and in postman but not when trying to access in javascript. I have added the photos showing response headers in network tab and on console tab. And also i am using axios for the request.

[image]

[image]

auth.js

```
...
export const authInit = (data) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authInitStart());
        axios.post('/login', data)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200){

                    const param = {
                        'Authorization': response.headers.Authorization
                    };
                    console.log("Authorization----" + JSON.stringify(response));
                    console.log("Param----" + JSON.stringify(param));
                    localStorage.setItem('Authorization', param['Authorization']);
                    dispatch(authInitSuccess(param['Authorization']));

                }else{
                    dispatch(authInitFail('Request failed'));
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                dispatch(authInitFail('Network error'));
            });

    };
};
...
```

param object is empty here

What can be the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Authorization header from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032464/read-authorization-header-from-response)

Comment: If you are using JSPs then you might be reading header value from JSP variable. 
In some cases, the JSP variable reads it's value even before the header gets set.

Comment: Thanks for your response @phuzi but it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your response @shubham. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization

response.headers.get('Authorization')

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers