# can't get response headers in react

Tags: javascript, axios, response-headers

```js
const sendRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    });

    console.log(response.data);

    const authorizationHeader = response.headers["Authorization"];
    if (authorizationHeader) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", authorizationHeader);
      console.log("Token stored in localStorage.");
    } else {
      console.log("No Authorization header received.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  }
};
```

this is my function above but even though I see the header I want to get "Authorization" on both network on chrome browser and postman I'm not able to get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) is a **request** header. It would be very odd for it to be present on a response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Authorization header from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032464/read-authorization-header-from-response)

Comment: I'm sending a token in Authorization header from my backend, should I change it then?

Comment: Pragmatically, you can send any header you want in the response but IMO, I would rename it to something like `x-auth-token`. You'll still need the appropriate `access-control-expose-headers` though (see the duplicate link). Even better would be to send it in a cookie

Comment: my backend is spring boot and security is really confusing me and my time is limited so is it worth changing atm?

Answer (score 1):

```
const authorizationHeader = response.headers['authorization'];
```

changing it the first letter of header name to lower case fixed my problem

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot... [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)... _"All header names are lowercase and can be accessed using the bracket notation."_